# Problems on OpenCV with IP Camera

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

Recently I am working on OpenCV to complete a design, I now have got an IP camera and just by typing the IP address of the camera and the port in my browser, like 192.168.1.1:8080, I can watch the video.
I have installed VS2010 and correctly complete the setting. I now can deal with pictures in my computer and capture videos of the camera on my computer. But when I tried to capture videos from IP camera by

`VideoCapture cap;
cap.open("http://192.168.137.235:8082/index.html")`

there is an error:

Error opening file (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:545)

so how can I solve the problem. Can anyone tell me specifically how to solve this problem?

Comment: index.html is not a video it is a web page..... VideoCapture won't parse your html and extract the video. You need to find the correct link, I would suggest the rtsp link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to capture video directly from my IP camera to OpenCV-based application directly via RTSP as it was advised previously. It works, but ffmpeg decoder works very unstable with RTSP stream from some cameras.
I found the next solution.
Some people like to perform live streaming of their PC screen to youtube. The standard tool for it is a XSplit Broadcaster.
This tool has a side-effect. It's able to create a virtual usb-webcam via RTSP-compatible IP camera.
OpenCV captures video from usb-webcams perfectly.
And basic license of XSplit Broadcaster is absolutely free.
Unfortunately this solution has a limitation. With no dependence on real resolution of your IP camera, resolution of virtual webcam will be 640*480

Comment: thanks.I have solved by playing the video on the screen and capture a picture of it to get the image.

Answer (score 0):

The page "index.html" could be only the main page of your video camera, the page where a human uses to navigate the camera and to watch the live.
The ip cameras are very different each of the others. If your ip camera is "onvif" it should have a rtsp socket. For example I can watch my ip camera using this path:

rtsp://address:554/onvif1

If you camera implements the mjpeg stream you shoult use the right path, for example

http://192.168.137.235:8082/live.html

To know wich is the righ way to connect to your camera, it is necessary to know wich is your camera.

Comment: thanks.I have solved by playing the video on the screen and capture a picture of it to get the image. Maybe it is because my video data is from Raspberry.